# How can I map an array of properties to a Bar with that properties in recharts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, recharts

I want to have a chart component in react(recharts) and when I use map function to map my properties array to bars with that props the problem is it doesn't show bars in my chart !
This is my code :

```js
export const HorizontalBarChart = (props: {
  data: Array<any>,
  properties: Array<any>,
}) => {
  const barItems = props.properties.map((obj) => {
    <Bar dataKey={obj.key}
      fill={obj.color}
      radius={[0, 10, 10, 0]}
    >
    </Bar>
  });

  return (
    <BarChart
      width={450}
      height={250}
      data={props.data}
      layout="vertical"
      margin={{
        top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5,
      }}
    >
      {barItems}
      <CartesianGrid horizontal={false} />
      <XAxis
        type="number"
        reversed={true}
        domain={[0, MAX]}
      //hide={true}
      />
      <YAxis type="category"
        dataKey="name"
        orientation="right"
        hide={true}
      />
    </BarChart>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

But when I implement bar tags manually it works ! like this :

```js
export const HorizontalBarChart = (props: {
  data: Array<any>,
  properties: Array<any>,
}) => {

  return (
    <BarChart
      width={450}
      height={250}
      data={props.data}
      layout="vertical"
      margin={{
        top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5,
      }}
    >
      <Bar dataKey={props.properties[1].key}
        fill={props.properties[1].color}
        radius={[0, 10, 10, 0]}
      >
      </Bar>
      <Bar dataKey={props.properties[2].key}
        fill={props.properties[2].color}
        radius={[0, 10, 10, 0]}
      >
      </Bar>
      {barItems}
      <CartesianGrid horizontal={false} />
      <XAxis
        type="number"
        reversed={true}
        domain={[0, MAX]}
      //hide={true}
      />
      <YAxis type="category"
        dataKey="name"
        orientation="right"
        hide={true}
      />
    </BarChart>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

And I'll be happy if you help me to solve this problem in recharts.

Comment: In you barItems functions you forgot to return Bar component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your current code there is a slight issue with barItems function

```
const barItems = props.properties.map((obj) => {
  <Bar dataKey={obj.key}
    fill={obj.color}
    radius={[0, 10, 10, 0]}
  >
  </Bar>
});
```

as you can see you forgot to return Bar component hence it returns nothing

Try this

```
const barItems = props.properties.map((obj) => {
  return (<Bar dataKey={obj.key}
    fill={obj.color}
    radius={[0, 10, 10, 0]}
  >
  </Bar>)
});
```

Or using fat arrow

```
const barItems = props.properties.map((obj) =>
  <Bar dataKey={obj.key}
    fill={obj.color}
    radius={[0, 10, 10, 0]}
  >
  </Bar>
);
```

Comment: Oops! I forgot to return that array ! Thank you very much ;)